# Break character string into components by matching regex

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse

## UPDATED QUESTION

I have this character vector

```r
str_ <- "H3K9me0S10ph1K14ac1me0"
```

I would like to break it into pieces such that I get an output like:

```r
"H3K9: me0 | S10: ph1 | K14: ac1,me0"
```

Preferably this is done in a manner that utilizes {dplyr}, such that I can perform this operation on a tibble and get a new column with the desired character string output. Any ideas?

As the below section suggests, I'm struggling with getting a table that denotes which modifications are paired with what, e.g. that the me0 goes with H3K9 and BOTH the ac1,me0 go with K14

Any assistance would be so helpful!

## Pieces of attempts

Using a slightly different example,

```r
str_ <- "H3K9ac1K14ac1K18ac1me0"
```

So I've tried breaking the character vector into pieces by extracting all "me[0-9]*" or "ac[0-9]*" etc, then giving them an id which corresponds to their index in the character vector.

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      i m    
  <int> <chr>
1    12 ac1  
2    17 ac1  
3    23 ac1  
4    26 me0
```

I need a way to create a column `together` that tells whether two modifications belong to the same protein, i.e. in this example K14 has ac1 and me0, so their 'together' values should be 'TRUE'. I've tried using the distance between their indices as a surrogate for togetherness, but I don't think this is the best way to do it:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      i m     unit_diff  together
  <int> <chr>    <int>     <lgl>
1    12 ac1       0          FALSE
2    17 ac1       5          FALSE
3    23 ac1       6          TRUE
4    26 me0       3          TRUE
```

Any ideas? I've tried using modulo 3, but this doesn't seem to generalize. Is this even the correct way to be doing this? I'm open to suggestions

Comment: This question is completely different from what was asked before. Making the solutions obsolete

Comment: @onyambu you're right I'm going to update the post so that it becomes more logical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff` to create the 'unit_diff' and then use `%%`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(unit_diff = c(0, diff(i)),
    together = unit_diff %% 3 == 0 & unit_diff != 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
      i m     unit_diff together
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>   
1    12 ac1           0 FALSE   
2    17 ac1           5 FALSE   
3    23 ac1           6 TRUE    
4    26 me0           3 TRUE
```

---

If we want to check the TRUE adjacent to `n` number of values, use `rleid` or `rle` from `base R`

```
library(data.table)
n <- 2
df1 %>% 
   mutate(unit_diff = c(0, diff(i)),
    together = unit_diff %% 3 == 0 & unit_diff != 0) %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(together)) %>%
   mutate(together = all(together) &  n() == n) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

---

For the second updated question, we can use regex to insert some delimiters - i.e. originally, we capture one or more characters that are not lowercase letters (`([^a-z]+)`) and replace with the backreference of the captured group followed by `:` (`\\1:`), then, we insert the `|` between characters that are a lowercase letter followed by digit and an uppercase letter, remove the lagging `:`  at the end with `trimws` and finally replace the `:` with `,` between the one or more lower case letter followed by one or more digits

```
gsub("([a-z]+\\d+):", "\\1,",
  trimws(gsub("(?<=[a-z][0-9])(?=[A-Z])", " | ", 
 gsub("([^a-z]+)", "\\1: ", str_), perl = TRUE), whitespace = ":\\s+"))
[1] "H3K9: me0 | S10: ph1 | K14: ac1, me0"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(i = c(12, 17, 23, 26), m = c("ac1", "ac1", "ac1", 
"me0")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: @NickCamarda when you say two rows are adjacent, what if it is 6, 3, 9

Comment: @NickCamarda your examples are somewhat confusing with description.  what if you have values like 0 6 5 3.  what would be the together

Comment: you're right - i'm still getting errors in my code - let me reframe the question

Comment: @NickCamarda I updated the post to make it generalizable.  Now, you can have any `n` value

Comment: I've updated my question now I hope that my problem is a little more clear -- I believe that you've given me a solution that is what I asked for but actually not what I need - could you please see the updated question?

Comment: @NickCamarda that distance part is not clear.  Are you trying to split based on a specific pattern i.e. between lowercase letter and a digit

Comment: the distance part was my effort at trying to determine whether two modifications are supposed to be together or not -- i don't think this is the best way to do it, since it seems overly complicated and prone to error. is there a way to just split this character vector in a way that gives me the updated desired output string?

Comment: @NickCamarda Perhaps you may try `trimws(gsub("(?<=[a-z][0-9])(?=[A-Z])", " | ", gsub("([^a-z]+)", "\\1: ", str_), perl = TRUE), whitespace = ":\\s+")`

Comment: this is super close - but I get this: ""H3K9: me0 | S10: ph1 | K14: ac1: me0"" where i'd like a comma between ac1 and me0

Comment: @NickCamarda yes, I updated in the post

Comment: This seems to work! Would you mind explaining the regex? I'm so bad at this -- thank you SO SO MUCH for your help

Comment: the regex doesn't quite work for this example: `H4(4to17)K5ac1me0` to
`H4(4: to17)K5: ac1, me0`. I don't want a colon after the "4" in "(4to17)"

Comment: @NickCamarda that would require some adjustments because the pattern I used was based on your original example.  I updated with some description

Comment: this works: ```gsub(x = gsub("([a-z]+\\d+):", "\\1,",
                    trimws(gsub("(?<=[a-z][0-9])(?=[A-Z])", " | ", 
                                gsub("([^a-z]+)", "\\1: ", str_), perl = TRUE), 
                           whitespace = ":\\s+")), pattern = ":\\s+t", replacement = "t")```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small function for your output: Note I am not very experienced in writing functions!

```
str_ <- "H3K9me0S10ph1K14ac1me0"


library(stringr)
library(knitr)

clean_func <- function(str_, x, y) {

x <- str_extract_all(str_, '([a-z]+[0-9]+)')[[1]]
y <- strsplit(str_replace_all(str_, paste(x, collapse = '|'), ' '), ' ')[[1]]
x[3] <- knitr::combine_words(x[3:4], and=",")
x1 <- x[1:3]
y1 <- y[1:3]
result <- paste(paste(y1, x1, sep = ": "), collapse = " | ")
return(result)
}

clean_func(str_)
```

```
[1] "H3K9: me0 | S10: ph1 | K14: ac1,me0"
```